# visual basic 2010 error with access database update query

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I have this code that should update my access database, but I keep getting an error saying:

> It is not possible so change or delete the regists because the table
>   'MembrosCompasso' has relating records.

This is my code:

```
Dim query1 As String = "UPDATE MembrosCompasso SET MembrosCompasso.BI=@compass_bi WHERE MembrosCompasso.BI=Membros.BI" ' Membros.Pai=@pai, Membros.Mae=mae WHERE BI=@BI"
Dim query As String = "UPDATE Membros  SET Membros.BI=@num_bi, Membros.Nome=@nome, Membros.Hablitacoes=@hablitacoes, Membros.Contribuinte=@contribuinte, Membros.Telemov=@telemov, Membros.DataNasc=@natnasc, Membros.LocalNasc=@localnasc, Membros.DataBaptismo=@databapt, Membros.LocalBapt=@localbapt, Membros.Sexo=@sexo, Membros.Naturalidade=@natu, Membros.Profissao=@prof, Membros.Estadocivil=@estadciv, Membros.DataCasamento=@datacas, Membros.LocalCasamento=@localcas, Membros.Notas=@notas, Membros.Email=@email WHERE Membros.BI=@BI" 

con.Close()
con.Open()
Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand(query1, con)
' Indicação dos parâmetros que serão actualizados

command1.Parameters.Add("@compass_bi", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = BI.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@num_bi", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = BI.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Nome.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@hablitacoes", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = hablitacoes.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@contribuinte", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ncront.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@telemov", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = telmov.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@natnasc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = datnasc.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@localnasc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NascLocal.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@databapt", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DataBapt.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@localbapt", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LocalBapt.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@sexo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = sexo.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@natu", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = natu.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@prof", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = profi.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@estadciv", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = estciv.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@datacas", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = datcas.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@localcas", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = localcas.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@notas", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = notas.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = email.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@BI", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = numero_BI
```

There is a screenshot of my access db schema [here](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/1697/30034667c.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to update the table `MembrosCompasso` before you make the change in table `Membros`.
Because you set `MembrosCompasso.BI` to be related to `Membros.BI`, it must exists in that table first.

If you set your relationship in Access to be automatically updated, you will not have to perform any manual update to `MembrosCompasso`, they will be updated automatically when you update the source field.

For instance, say I have a `PO` table that has many `POItem`.
I could set the one-to-many relationship between them as below:

[image]

In that case, if I update `PO.ID`, all `POItem.POID` fields will be updated.
Same if I delete a given `PO` record, all related `POItem` records will also be deleted.

Have a look at the [MS Access documentation about table relationships](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HA010341733&lcid=1033&NS=MSACCESS&Version=14&tl=2&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=178799).